# PostgreSQL Copy To - CSV filename encoding

Tags: postgresql, csv, encoding

I have a database setup with a UTF-8 encoding. Trying to copy a table to csv, where the filename has a special character writes out the filename wrong to disk.

On a Windows 10 localhost PostgreSQL installation:

```
copy
  (select 'tønder')
to 'C:\temp\Sønderborg.csv' (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, DELIMITER ';', ENCODING 'UTF8');
```

Names the csv file: SÃ¸nderborg.csv and not Sønderborg.csv.

Both

```
SHOW CLIENT ENCODING;
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
```

returns UTF8

How can one control the csv filename encoding? The encoding inside the csv is ok writing Tønder!

**UPDATE**

I have run the *copy* command from pgAdmin, DataGrip and a psql console. DataGrip uses JDBC and will only handle UTF8. All three applications writes the csv filename in wrong encoding. The only difference is that the psql console says the client encoding is WIN1252.

Comment: What program are you using to run the `copy` command?

Comment: I updated the question with program running the copy command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change this behaviour. It looks like Postgres assumes that the filename encoding matches the `server_encoding` (as suggested on the mailing lists [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/550FE0B8.70803%40realfusio.com) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/5110DC53.7080409%40gesteam.fr)). The only workaround I could find was to run the command while connected to a `WIN1252`-encoded database, which is probably not very helpful.

If you're trying to run this on the same machine as the server itself, then instead of using the server-side [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), you can run `psql`'s client-side [`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY), which will respect your `client_encoding` when interpreting the file path:

```
psql -c "\copy (select 'tønder') to 'C:\temp\Sønderborg.csv' (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, DELIMITER ';', ENCODING 'UTF8')"
```

Note that `cmd.exe` (and even `powershell.exe`) still uses legacy DOS encodings by default, so you might need to run `chcp 1252` to set the console codepage before launching `psql`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the psql \copy returns the correct filename.